# how can a windows application installed via wine be enabled to access partitions other than /home?

Tags: partitioning, wine, software-installation

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, having only recently switched from Windows. As I  had a very large number of files stored in several partitions, which I naturally wanted to retain, I deleted only the partition C where Windows OS was, and manually installed Ubuntu 14.04 (with its 'swap', '/root' and '/home') in that space.

Now I do quite a bit of video conversion, my desired output formats being Xvid, MP3 and -- for container -- AVI. Since Handbrake video converter  allows only MKV container, I installed via Wine my preferred Windows application, Mediacoder. I find that this application does convert video files as before (which means the installation has been correctly done) ***but only those from the ubntu '/home' partition***. It cannot even detect the other pre-existing partitions, let alone accessing files from them.

So my question is:

How can a Windows-compatible application, installed via Wine, be enabled to detect and access partitions that were created earlier by Windows?

Answer (score 0):

To find files stored outside of `/home`, reach `/home/<user>/.wine/dosdevices/z:` (where  is your username). This is a symlink to your root folder (`/`). From there, you can look for your files anywhere on the system, for example in /media if there are partitions mounted in that folder.

Make sure you possess the rights to read the files you need. If necessary, you can change them in a file manager (under a file's properties window) or, in a terminal, by using either `chmod u+x` followed by the files or `chmod u+x -R` followed by folders.

Comment: Meanwhile I have found the answer, helped by the responses to a question that asked how to enable a Wine-installed application to access NTFS partitions (this way of putting the question is much better than mine). The method is more or less similar to above. But the crucial point is that you must first MOUNT the particular file system where your target file is, for Wine cannot mount; you have to do it yourself. I hope this helps those who are facing a similar problem.